# Does it cost more to run an ELB in more than one availability zone?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I see that you can specify what availability zones an ELB serves.  Right now, we're only setting a single EC2 instance up in a single AZ.  But someday, we'll have multiple across AZ's for redundancy.  Is there any reason I shouldn't just set up the ELB to serve two now, so I don't have to change it later?

Does it cost more to run your load balancer in multiple availability zones?  Are there any other drawbacks to running an ELB in multiple AZ's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't cost more to run load balancer in multi-az. Load Balancer costs are fix for every region, it does not vary for availability zones. Its better to have ELB right now, because when you need will increase and you add more instances to your account, you don't have to change URL in your application. ELB provides a seperate URL and in the background you can add more instances to it without any change to URL. If you provide DNS of instance right now in your application and in future, your plan to expand and have ELB, you need to change URL in application i.e., URL where your clients should connect.

Comment: Yup, definitely going ELB, just didn't know to go single AZ or multi AZ with it right now.  Thanks.